# python simple binance bot beginner

Tags: binance

I have a simple binance bot for my cryptocurrency trading.
The code is shown below:

```
from binance.client import Client#from Binance Sir Sam Chardy
from time import sleep

api_key = ''
api_secret = ''

client = Client(api_key,api_secret)
Altcoin=''
Symbol=''

class Balance:
def UsdtBalance(self):
    x=client.get_asset_balance(asset='')
    x=float(x['free'])
    return x
def AltcoinBalance(self):
    x=client.get_asset_balance(asset=Altcoin)
    x=float(x['free'])
    return x

a=Balance()
US=a.UsdtBalance()
AL=a.AltcoinBalance()

while order = False
   if US > AL:
        x=client.get_historical_klines(symbol=Symbol,interval='1m',start_str='1min ago UTC')
        a=float(x[0][1]
        d=float(x[0][4]
        if a > d and a < 0.997:
        print('BUY')
        client.order_market_buy(symbol=Symbol,quantity=100,price=d)
        else:
            pass
   if US > AL:
        x=client.get_historical_klines(symbol=Symbol,interval='1m',start_str='1min ago UTC')
        a=float(x[0][1]
        d=float(x[0][4]
        if a < d and a > 1.001:
        print('SELL')
        client.order_market_sell(symbol=Symbol,quantity=100,price=d)
        else:
            pass
sleep(8)
```

My problem with this code is that the moment the condition to buy or a condition to sell is satisfied the program will stop and I will run again the code to continue. I want it to continue indefinitely with out my intervention so that it will be truly autonomous.

I will very much appreciate  your answers.
Thank you.
#messy code beginner programmer

Comment: This looks wrong: `while order = False`. It should be `while order == False:`

Answer (score -1):

before your first while begin with

```
while True:
```

and it will star over again and again

Answer (score -1):

Try using a websocket and a run_forever() and correct the while loop as described above. Hope this helps